# How can I call android system service like wifi_service in my uiautomator project?

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator, autotest

```
public String getMacInfo(){    
    String mac = "";    
       WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);    
       WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();    
       if(wifiInfo.getMacAddress()!=null){    
        mac = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();    
    } else {    
        mac = "Fail";    
    }    

       return mac;    
}
```

I add these code in my test case ,there is a error

showing in "mContext" the line 3.

Who can help me???

Thank you !

Comment: What is the error? NPE? "Cannot find symbol"? or something else?

Comment: mContext cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1):

The "mContext cannot be resolved" error means that variable "mContext" is not in scope (or is not declared anywhere).

The fix is simple, you just need to declare the object as a member variable, and initialize it in your setUp() method.

```
public class MyTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    private Context mContext;

    public void setUp() {
        mContext = getInstrumentation().getContext();
    }

    // ...
}
```

See [Java, "Variable name" cannot be resolved to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588784/java-variable-name-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable) for a similar question regarding this particular error.

Comment: thanks ！i am green hand ，add the code you given can't run correctly ，why？the error is    <pre>The method getInstrumentation() is undefined for the type baidumap<code>,the "baidumap" is my test case extends UiAutomatorTestCase! do you know how to modify  ! Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a recent version of UiAutomator (v2.0 or  higher)?

Comment: i think not,the uiautomator.jar file is in android-19 sdk which my colleague shared. I must  use the recent version?

Comment: Shell-based UiAutomator (the old version) cannot access the Context object. This is possible with UiAutomator v2.0 or later.