# use method of one class in another class of different package

Tags: java

I have the below code:

```
public class class1 {
.............

public static void calls(String[] args) {

    ................
```

Now I am trying to call this method "calls" of "class1" in an another class within an another method like below code:

```
public class newClass extends abc {

public void executemywork() throws CIException {

class1.calls(args); //error here "args" cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I have tried looking at other solutions in stack overflow. I even tried by creating object of "class1" and using it in the second method. I am still getting the same error here. The error says "args" cannot be resolved to a variable. Both The classes are in different packages and I have imported the other class as well.

Comment: The call is fine. The problem is, as the error message says, you haven't defined `args`, which is something you're passing **into** `calls`.

Comment: You didn't declare your variable args in the newClass  class

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the location of the method. You simply do not have anything named `args`.

Comment: This is a duplicate, possibly of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588784/java-variable-name-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable, but I'm still looking...

Comment: Si if i initialize as String[] args = null;     this should do the job

Comment: Extra: Java Convention remark. Class names start with Capital letters and static method calls should be called on the class.

Answer (score 3):

Declare and give a value to args like

```
String[] args = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a `compilation error`
You are doing `class1.calls(args);` but here `args` is not defined. Hence the compilation error.

Change your code something like

```
public class newClass extends abc {

            public void executemywork() throws CIException {
                    String[] args = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
                    class1.calls(args); //error here "args" cannot be resolved to a variable
            }
}
```